# Global boolean not being accesable by anoter class

Tags: java, boolean, listener, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to code a Minecraft plugin, that with one command makes all creepers that spawn charge, and with another makes them all uncharged. I have written the code that sets listeners(and by that, I mean I copied Dream's code from https://youtu.be/oHKcQ184aa8?t=22) and I just want to make it so there is a boolean that goes in the place of true in the following code(last line)
'''

```
    @EventHandler
    public void creeperSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntityType() == EntityType.CREEPER) {
            Creeper creeper = (Creeper) event.getEntity();
            creeper.setPowered(true);
        }
    }
```

'''
   I want to change the true to a booolean named PoweredOrNot, and then when the command is run, it sets it Powered or not to true. The only problem being that it either says that PoweredOrNot is not defined, or when I add extends onCommand, it gives me the error "Syntax error on token "extends", throws expected"
and two other errors , one on a bracket above saying "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody",which adding another bracket doesn't work. and another error on a bracket below saying "Syntax error on token "}", delete this token, which deleting gets rid of the error.

I did research and made another class named Globals and it has the boolean name powered or not too, but when I did Globals.PoweredOrNot it would say it wasnt defined

here is the jar file for you to decompile as there are many classes and packages to work with. note, I think you might have to have the reference libraries for spiggot downloaded but idk if that is included in the jar.
    https://drive.google.com/file/d/18XWOHV13I2cB---xlG0socfRMOnnKfPv/view?usp=sharing

FULL code (for the startCommand class)

```
package me.Gwehyr.chargeall.commands;

import org.bukkit.entity.Creeper;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.command.*;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.CreatureSpawnEvent;

import me.Gwehyr.chargeall.*;


public class StartCommand implements CommandExecutor, Listener {

    private Main plugin;

    public StartCommand(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("charge").setExecutor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand( CommandSender sender,  Command cmd,  String label, String[] args) {
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            sender.sendMessage("Only Console may execute this command");
            return true;
        }else {
            boolean PoweredOrNot = true;
            sender.sendMessage("Creepers Charged!");
        }
        return true;
    }

@EventHandler
public void creeperSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent event) extends onCommand {
    if (event.getEntityType() == EntityType.CREEPER) {
        Creeper creeper = (Creeper) event.getEntity();
        creeper.setPowered(PoweredOrNot);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! This is a place for professional/enthusiast developers to ask questions and get answers. You should find resources online and learn at least the basics of Java before considering using the Bukkit API. The code you shared wouldn't compile and this is an otherwise trivial issue.

Comment: @Lucan I have learned the very basics of java in school before the stay at home order here in America, but I had never done anything outside of the "public static void main(String[]  args)" before, and never anything with ,multiple methods. I know mostly python because that's what we did at the beginning of the year. but java was the thing i was most excited for. if you could point me to some resources for learning java(for free) that would be nice and i could solve my problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it says it's not initialized is because it is only initialized inside your onCommand function. So instead of putting your boolean here (where the arrow is)

```
public boolean onCommand( CommandSender sender,  Command cmd,  String label, String[] args) {
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            sender.sendMessage("Only Console may execute this command");
            return true;
        }else {
            boolean PoweredOrNot = true;   <---------
            sender.sendMessage("Creepers Charged!");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

put up the top of your class.

```
public boolean PoweredOrNot;
```

This makes sure it is defined and if you want to be able to access this boolean from another class (I'm not sure why you would, it depends on what you are making), instead you can put

```
public static boolean PoweredOrNot;
```

This doesn't have a value by default so you might want to set it to false or something.

Also to the people saying for people new to Bukkit/coding in general, don't tell them to "learn before they start", it's good to get help and it prevents them from doing it next time. Hope this helped!

Comment: Haha thanks, I will try this. I came on to ask another question about Steam controllers and saw I got a reply. and yeah, I thought him telling me to learn how to code was kind of stupid. Like what do you think I came here for?

Comment: Yeah, I hope it does end up working end if it does, mark it as correct. :)

Comment: it worked btw, I fixed it like a year ago and never came back. thanks for your help lol. I'm much more experienced with this stuff now lmao.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked and good to see that you are still programming. Take care mate.